# Convert CRC function from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++

I am trying to convert this function from C++

```
BYTE serial::CalcCRC(BYTE start, const BYTE *buffer, DWORD lenght) 
{
    BYTE CRC = start; //...
    for(DWORD count = 0 ; count < lenght ; count++) CRC += buffer[count];
    return (0-CRC);
}
```

to C#.
This is my C# code:

```
 public byte CalcCRC(byte start, byte[] buffer, int length)
 {
     byte crc = start;
     for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) crc += buffer[i];
     return (0 - crc);
 }
```

But I get this error on the last line:

> error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'byte'. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

How can I convert above function to C#? Also I think that C++ function may **overflow** most of the times, will I get same behaviour on C# side?

Ok now that I think cast may solve the error - but will I get same behaviour with my C# function as with C++ function, mainly due to the behaviour which may occur on overflow, etc.

Comment: `return (byte)(0 - crc);`

Comment: @RahulTripathi: Yeah  but what about overflows, etc?

Comment: Note that you don't need to pass in `length` for C# you can get that from `buffer.Length` instead.

Comment: @juharr: Yeah but is my C# implementation equivalent? What about overflows?

Comment: You'll likely want to wrap that in an `unchecked` section to make sure the overflow doesn't throw (the default is unchecked, but that can be changed as a compiler option, and it's best to be explicit).  I would assume that overflow occurs the same in C++ and C#, but I'm not a C++ expert.

Comment: @juharr: I passed this array : `{122,33,22,199,199};` to both C++ and C# code and got same result

Comment: @juharr: But I still want to know if my C# version is same as C++ version

Comment: If you mean will it give the same results for the same input I'm pretty sure it will.  Except when `length` exceeds the actual length of the array.  Then C# will throw an exception while C++ may or may not throw based on the location of the memory.

Comment: @juharr: Yes I am interested if it will give same result for same input

Comment: @user300224 "But I still want to know if my C# version is same as C++ version". This is the perfect time to write some unit tests agains the c++ and convert those into c# as well. Then you'll know.

Comment: By the way, `byte[] something` is invalid declaration in C/C++.  you might write `byte something[]` or `byte *something`.  Also, to be conservative, you might declare it `const` to disallow modifying the buffer contents.

Comment: @LuisColorado: That is C#

Comment: So why is this question tagged c++?

Comment: @LuisColorado:why not

Comment: C++ is not C#.  You might know.  The original C++ code not even appears in the question.  So no C++ code, nor anything C++ related.  Just a C# question, it should not be tagged C++.  By the way, the algorithm is not for a CRC checksum, but for an arithmetic sum checksum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would translate that

```
public byte CalcCRC(byte start, byte[] buffer)
{
    unchecked
    {
        byte crc = start;
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            crc += buffer[i];
        return (byte)(0 - crc);
    }
}
```

The `unchecked` will make sure that the overflow will not result in an exception.  While that is the default, it can be changed as a compiler option.

The main difference here is that this will not allow you to enter a length that doesn't match up with the actual length of the array.  In C++ that would have undefined behavior while in C# it would throw an exception because C# has array bounds checking.

And overflow is the same in both C# and C++ in that the left most binary digits are truncated based on the size of the data type.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that your original byte is converted into a integer the moment you do "0 - crc". So what you will need to do is have the last line

```
return (byte)(0-crc);
```

And that should fix the problem.

The reason it "converts" itself into a integer is that the numeric value is per default a integer. And doing Integer - Byte = Integer

EDIT:
About the overflow will not happen, but to avoid possible problems you can make sure that the value does not exceed 255

So what you will have to do is have an additional check

```
if( crc + buffer[i] < Byte.MaxValue )
    crc += buffer[i];
```

Comment: That wasn't the main question, though.

Comment: what about overflows?

Comment: In the substraction `crc` will be converted to `int` before operation.

Comment: I believe the question is if overflows happen the same in C++ and C#, not how to avoid the overflow.

Comment: My bad. Then No. it shouldnt happen :-)

Comment: `if( crc + buffer[i] < Byte.MaxValue )` - there is no such check on the C++ side, and I need to get same output on the C# function as on the C++ function given I pass same parameters

Comment: In `Integer - Byte = Integer` operation `Byte` will become `Integer` then the operation will be `Integer - Integer = Integer`.